# Quotes issue in bash while executing python cmd line

Tags: python, bash

i am running a python command per below in bash env, it runs fine :

```
python -c "from ami_management import cleanup; cleanup.main(['10', 'ctm'])"
```

But when i am passing variables :

```
amis_to_retain="10"
ami_prefix="ctm"
python -c "from ami_management import cleanup;cleanup.main([$amis_to_retain, $ami_prefix])"
```

then it fails.
Somehow not able to figure out how to pass these variables with single quotes instead of double quotes.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put quotes inside quotes.

```bash
python -c "from ami_management import cleanup;cleanup.main(['$amis_to_retain', '$ami_prefix'])"
```